# Is libumem is available only in Solaris OS or in other OS too?

Tags: debugging, memory, memory-management, solaris, libumem

Is libumem is available only  in Solaris OS or in other OS too

Answer (score 0):

*libumem* is available only for Solaris OS (OpenSolaris, OpenIndiana, Solaris) since SunOS 5.9 (Solaris 9).

On *sourceforge* you have a port, but I think is too old, [port of Solaris libumem at SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/umem/)

Urko,